# Multiple columns on left side of IN condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-in

This is a valid statement:

```
SELECT foo FROM table1 WHERE
  column1 IN (SELECT bar FROM table2) AND
  column2 IN (SELECT bar FROM table2)
```

But is there any way we can avoid repeating the `SELECT bar FROM table2` statement to make it simpler and more economical?

I mean something like this:

```
SELECT foo FROM table1 WHERE
  «column1 and also column2» IN (SELECT bar FROM table2)
```

Comment: I don't think there is a *simpler* way of expressing this logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a co-related sub-query with an EXISTS operator

```
select *
from table1 t1
where exists (select *
              from table2 t2
              where t2.bar in (t1.column1, t1.column2));
```

If both columns should match the value in `table2.bar` the following can be used:

```
select *
from table1 t1
where exists (select *
              from table2 t2
              where t2.bar = t1.column1
                and t2.bar = t1.column2);
```

Comment: This is not the same.  This would be the same if the original query had `or`, but it has `and`.  I understand the answer, but not that it was accepted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: yes you are right. Salman's answer treats that as an AND condition.

Answer (score 3):

You could use aggregation:

```
select *
from table1
where exists (
    select 1
    from table2
    where table2.bar in (table1.column1, table1.column2)
    having count(distinct bar) = case when table1.column1 = table1.column2 then 1 else 2 end
);
```

So if table1 contains the pair `(foo, bar)` and table2 contain values `(foo), (baz)` it ***won't*** match.